# spring.application.name not working and showing the service registered as config-default only instead of a custom service name

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

In my application.properties file, I set the spring.application.name = CART-SERVICE but while trying to register it to the eureka server it is displaying as CONFIG-DEFAULT instead of CART-SERVICE. I am using git to hold the configuration.

[Attached Screenshot of eureka server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nqxy.png)

I tried using spring.config.name but it is also giving me the same results.

What should I do so the name of the service is displayed on the server instead of just registering as CONFIG-DEFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

This name is to be added in
*bootstrap.properties* file and not application.properties.

Comment: I tried this also but it is still not registering as a customized name.

I also checked the version of spring cloud that I am using, it is still not working the way I want it too.

Comment: Can you start the app with debug logs and add them here ,